# How do I move screens in the app drawer?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-5, app-drawer

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5.  I have a bunch of apps installed.  From the home screen, I can tap on the Apps icon.  This takes me to the App Drawer.  In the App Drawer, I have 2 screens full of icons of apps.  I have a 3rd screen full of folders with icons of apps in them.  I would like to move the 3rd screen so that it becomes the first screen.  How do I do this?

If I were on the Home Screen, I can long press to allow editing the screens.  Here I can long press on a screen and move it to the left or right of other screens and reposition them.

This doesn't work in the App Drawer.  I can't seem to do this in the App Drawer.  I tap on the menu and tap on Edit.  I am not able to reposition the screens.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't move whole screens, just individual apps.

Comment: You can't, and I don't think you can on any custom launcher either I'm afraid. You could try Nova / Apex / Go launcher or similar (all are free) and see if they meet your needs.